# Missing prop Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un mapping de un objeto en ReactJS a través de un consumidor, cuando intento hacer el mapeo me da el siguiente error:

> Failed to compile
>
> **./src/js/views/files_view/files.js c:\Users\pc\Desktop\final\proyecto-final-2\src\js\views\files_view\files.js
>   16:8  error  Missing "key" prop for element in iterator  react/jsx-key
>   ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)**

Mi codigo para el mapeo es el siguiente:

```
<Context.Consumer>
            {({ store, actions }) => {
                return store.files.map((fil, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-sm-4" key={i}>
                                    <i className="fa fa-file-pdf fa-3x" /> <br />
                                    <small>Archivo: {fil.file_name}</small> <br />
                                    <small>Subido: {fil.created}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                });
            }}
        </Context.Consumer>
```

Comment: Creo que el error puede darse por no tener definido la propiedad `key` en el contenedor del componente. Es decir, tu lo estás ubicando en un hijo del padre, y debe estar dentro del padre, es decir en tu div con clase `container`, quedando así `<div className="container" key={i}>` y podrías eliminarlo del otro div con clase `col-sm-4`

Comment: @GermanAlzate gracias por la respuesta, he intentado poner el key dentro del container como dices pero me hace un container individual para cada archivo leido. lo que intento es que en el col-sm pueda ir el archivo y este alimente el col-sm.

Comment: Pero entonces el error que tienes ya sería diferente al de la pregunta, el error que te sale y que agregas en la pregunta se soluciona de la forma que te indico. La lógica de lo que estés programando viene a ser otro tema

Comment: @GermanAlzate mi error pude todo en el return, dbia haber puesto sol el col-sm en el return statement y aplicarle la key a ello. solucionado! :D

Answer (score 0):

te esta diciendo que le estas pasando un objeto tipo `iterator` no un `iterable`. y que no puede encontrar una llave para este.

pero no hay nada mejor que un **ejemplo:**

```js
a = [1,2,3,4,5];
b= {a:1,b:2};

// !! es para hacer un cast a boolean
console.log(!!a[Symbol.iterator]())

// !! es para hacer un cast a boolean
console.log(!!b[Symbol.iterator]())
```

> como ves el tipo `iterator` es solo para los los `arreglos`

una posible solucion es pasar tu `arreglo` a `objeto` **ejemplo:**

```js
a = ["a","b","c"];
b = { ...a };

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```